# EditText default value and variable name

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there a way to have an edittext show the hint but to have a 0 value and if you click to input your value,the 0 disappears ? I'd like this as a solution to having empty editTexts that make my app crash.

How can i name my EditText with a variable ? For example : EditText cant1=(EditText) findViewById(1);
Instead of cant1 to have something like EditText cant+i=(EditText) findViewById(i);i++; I want to loop and register the EditTexts automatically but i need it to change the names.I mean,to name it cant1 then cant2 then cant3 and so on.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

In your XML add `android:hint="Username"` and what ever is in the brackets will show up in the edit text but won't equal anything.

And in your java you can do a null check or surround it in a try/catch to prevent app crashing:

`EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);`

```
if(et != null) {  
    //Do stuff  
}else{  
    //Toast an error or a warning  
}
```

or

```
try{  
    String value = et.getText();
}catch(NullPointerException e){
    //Toast an error or a warning
}
```

Comment: I know about the hint thing,i'm already using it.I was talking about a value,a 0 that stays there,under the hint,until you click.Is there a command for that ? Or do i need to code some kind of on click stuff,not really knowing this command very well.Also,how about the EditText variable in the name ?

Comment: You could do something like check to see if the edit text is null, and if it is set the variable to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Then,add 0 as hint.But,if you want both hint text and '0' at a time i think it is not possible. Try edittext.setText("0");in coding place and check it out...i am not sure it may work.